# convert all pdf pages into image

Tags: php, pdf

In php using Imagick, I'm able to convert one pdf page into a jpg image at once. But I need to convert all pages of my pdf into jpg files in separate folder.

below my code

```
<?php 
  for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){
  $pdf_file   = 'book.pdf';
  $save_to    = 'pages/tw'.$i.'.jpg';
  $img = new imagick();
  $img->setResolution(200,200);
  $img->readImage("{$pdf_file}[$i]");
  $img->scaleImage(800,0);
  $img->setImageFormat('jpg'); 
  $img = $img->flattenImages();
  $img->writeImages($save_to, false);
  $img->destroy();     
 }
 ?>
```

Above code produces results up-to 10 pages. Then it terminated by execution time of 30 secs. I cant manage `php.ini` because I'm using hosting with another company.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $mypdf = escapeshellarg( "mysafepdf.pdf" );

  $newjpg = escapeshellarg( "output.jpg" );

  $result = 0;

  exec("convert -density 600 {$mypdf} {$newjpg} -colorspace RGB -resample 300", null, $result);
```

*$ result will be 0 if the conversion works*

*-density = dpi*

I hope this will help you!

PS.: This is only for one image, but you can adapt at it for your $i.

Comment: i tried this exec method but i cant get good quality so i moved to imagick Class based conversion. i expecting based on imagick Class.

Comment: have you increased the DPI?